# PostGIS syntax (function()).*

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Whilst reading the documentation about using the PostGIS function [ST_PixelAsCentroids()](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsCentroids.html) I was confused somewhat by this `(ST_PixelAsPoints(rast, 1)).*` syntax and as a newbie to SQL I was wondering if someone could explain this convention and why it's used?

It's obviously used as a method to unbundle complex results but I don't even know what it is called to google it properly to get a formal understanding of it.

I realise this post may be better suited to a SQL forum on Stack but I'll see what GIS Stack conjures up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns a table with typed columns (a schema) and rows (values). The `.*` at the end means "all columns from the table." `SELECT * FROM f(x)` would give a similar output to `SELECT (f(x)).*`.

Due to [a PostgreSQL quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query) functions with multiple columns may be called once for each column by the query planner in the cases above. So it is advised to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) or subquery to prevent this behaviour, writing for example:

```
SELECT (mf).* FROM (
    SELECT my_func(x) AS mf FROM some_table OFFSET 0
) sub;
```

or in PostgreSQL 9.3

```
SELECT mf.*
FROM some_table
LEFT JOIN LATERAL my_func(some_table.x) AS mf ON true;
```

Comment: The two forms aren't quite equivalent; `SELECT * FROM function()` will execute the function once, `SELECT (function()).*` will execute the function once per column in the output.

Comment: I edited with a link to a good stackoverflow Q & A explaining the issue @dbaston raised

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a PostgreSQL question rather than a PostGIS question, but sill a good one.

Functions like `ST_PixelAsPoints`, `ST_PixelAsPolygons`, and `ST_PixelAsCentroids` return a set of composite record data type, which have several fields. This is very similar to ST_Dump, [described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24723/1872). To gain access to all the returned fields from these composite data types, they need to be in the form `(function(x)).*`, as [described in the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#AEN7383).

Note that `function(x).*` will not work, and is a common gotcha.